# Jest watch not detecting changes to files

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

Running `npm t -- --watch` is not detecting changes to test files. If I run `npm t` or `npm run test:changed` (my script for only running tests that cover changed files via `jest -o`) everything works fine, however, no changes are ever detected and the tests aren't re-run.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

For extra context, I'm using [`ts-jest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-jest) and here are some of my relevant config files:

`src/tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "include": ["./**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "./**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

`jest.config.ts`

```
module.exports = {
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsConfig: 'src/tsconfig.json',
    },
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
  roots: ['src'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  testMatch: ['**/*.test.(ts|js)'],
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  collectCoverageFrom: ['./src/**/*.ts', '!./src/migration/**', '!./src/tests/**'],
  coverageDirectory: './',
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      statements: 60,
      branches: 45,
      functions: 35,
      lines: 60,
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that I configured Jest to use `./` for the coverage location (everything was `.gitignore`'d, so who cares ¯\_(ツ)_/¯) and that was creating problems. More info can be found on the [relevant issue on the Jest repo](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4428).

Answer (score 1):

try `npm jest --clearCache`
Sometimes jests cache stops catching the changes also if you are using typescript try deleting your dist folder and rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a config had set the test to run in `--runInBand` mode. If you remove this, the watch works.